# Add multichoice question to quiz node programmatically

Tags: hooks, quiz

I'm using the latest version of drupal and quiz module. In my custom module, I have created a quiz by using below code

```
 $quiz = new stdClass();
  $quiz->title = 'Testing Quiz';
  $quiz->type = 'quiz';
  $quiz->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
  $quiz->uid = 1;
  $quiz->status = 1;
  node_object_prepare($quiz);
  $quiz = node_submit($quiz);
  node_save($quiz);
```

However, the quiz is created successfully. I have a list of multichoice question, which is imported using feeds module. Now what I want is assign those multichoice question to this custom quiz node.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution. The below code is used to add the multichoice question node to quiz node.

```
  $multichoice_node = node_load($nid); //load multichoice question nid  
  $multichoice_node->add_directly = array(
    'latest' => array(
      $quiz->nid. '-'. $quiz->vid => $quiz->nid. '-'. $quiz->vid
    )
  );
  node_save($multichoice_node);
```